# Possibility of high transaction failure rate using WATCH, MULTI, EXEC in Redis

Tags: redis, transactions, race-condition

I will be storing key-value pairs in Redis but the number of keys will be just 4. Since there will be multiple processes updating the values parallelly, I plan to use Redis transactions using `WATCH`, `MULTI` and `EXEC` commands.

My algorithm is something like this:

```
GET key
WATCH key
MULTI
    SET key new_val
EXEC
```

My main concern is that, since `WATCH` uses optimistic locking, when I will have multiple processes (much more than the number of keys, which are only 4) trying to update values, the transaction failure rate will be very high.

Is this correct? Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear why you'd need a transaction here unless you're doing something in your application with the reply for `GET key`. I'll therefore assume that you are using the value for something meaningful, otherwise, you can drop the transaction semantics and just call `SET key new_val`.

Optimistic locking is mainly intended to be used in cases where there's low contention for the resources. Since the use case that you're describing is clearly the opposite, it would probably result in high failure rates. This isn't saying that Redis and your application will not work, but it does mean there a potential for a lot of wasted effort.

I would advise that you consider switching if possible to using Redis' server-side Lua scripts. These are blocking, atomic, and let you read and meaningfully manipulate the data in Redis programmatically. See the [`EVAL`](https://redis.io/commands/eval) command for details.